# Create type having common props from other types and other optional

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have following three interfaces:

```
type A = {
    x: string
    y: string
}

type B = {
    y: string
}

type C = {
    z: string;
    y: string;
}
```

There are common required properties here. And there're required properties which are not part of the rest of 2 types. So, my question is:

Is there way to create type that unites common props and makes other properties optional? E.g.:

```
type D = {
    y: string
    x?: string
    z?: string
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For many use-cases, the union type `A | B | C` will behave this way, but stricter in the sense that you can't have "optional" properties from more than one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few ways to do this, but one solution would be to create a type `Pick<T1, keyof T1 & keyof T2 & keyof T3>` that has the properties shared by three types `T1` to `T3`, and intersect it with an object `Partial<T1 & T2 & T3>` that has optional properties for any properties in `T1` to `T3`.

```
type CommonRequiredRestOptional<T1, T2, T3> =
  Pick<T1, keyof T1 & keyof T2 & keyof T3> & Partial<T1 & T2 & T3>
```

The partial object will also contain the required properties, but because of the intersection these stay required (`T & (T | undefined)` is `T`).

A helper `TopLevelNormalize` can be used to show the actual object type rather than `Pick<A, "y"> & Partial<A & B & C>`:

```
type TopLevelNormalize<T> = T extends infer S ? {[K in keyof S]: S[K]} : never;

type Test = TopLevelNormalize<CommonRequiredRestOptional<A, B, C>>
// type Test = { y: string; x?: string | undefined; z?: string | undefined;}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQTgG8AoOcuEALjgGcYpkBzAbjIoE8b7GlWSAviRKhIsRCjRZccAELF25LnQbM2QkeGjxkqDDjwBhBRTgAvbqr5tTynmsHCYHMEYgBbdxCQAlYAEcAVwQoYAATP3oAeTAYBG9MABsAHgAVAEYAGjhUgCZs1IBmAD44AF52AAUEbABrNKy4WuAOCHQc9LgAMiaWtpzc7t7W9qLSnsrMWAQkhqG8+ZKnFzxUiDAAGWAAN2BEgDlodySEM2A00rKcuFBUJDDaCXQ0OABlOAB+YgBtAGkJYb9V4AXRorz+wIEcBoSB2aGWrhywHo5Ry6y2uwORxOZ2Shg8Xl8AWCoQiyJgMTiCRS+GysmyhmKxRIAHoWXBnIjUuTUUQ4HYrKxKB9LLwmHAAD5wQL3YDoZDhFjmEUqMWS6Wy+WwsIsDSc1bkwZXfGebx+IIhcKRCmxeJIWa0uQM5lAA)

Answer (score 1):

*Whilst working on this solution, I tried to create an implementation that used generics but didn't get anywhere. I'm sure that a TypeScript wizard could derive a generic solution from mine!*

First, let's create a utility type for finding properties that are "common":

```
type Common = {
  [key in keyof A & keyof B & keyof C]: A[key] | B[key] | C[key]
}
```

Now we can find properties from one of your interfaces that are "uncommon":

```
{
  // Properties only in A
  [key in keyof Exclude<A, keyof Common>]?: A[key]
}
```

Putting this altogether, we get this:

```
export interface A {
  x: string
  y: string
}

export interface B {
  y: string
}

export interface C {
  z: string
  y: string
}

/**
 * Common properties in A, B, and C.
 */
type Common = {
  [key in keyof A & keyof B & keyof C]: A[key] | B[key] | C[key]
}

/**
 * All properties from A, B, and C.
 * 
 * Properties that are "common" (in all interfaces) are required,
 * others (not present in all interfaces) are optional.
 */
type D = Common & {
  // Properties only in A
  [key in keyof Exclude<A, keyof Common>]?: A[key]
} & {
  // Properties only in B
  [key in keyof Exclude<B, keyof Common>]?: B[key]
} & {
  // Properties only in C
  [key in keyof Exclude<C, keyof Common>]?: C[key]
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQTgG8AoOOEALjgGcYpkBzMuAT2roaWYF8STQkWIhRosuOACFiLdrXpMSfAeGjxkqDDjwBhGeQBeHBd1nGuvfgHoAVDbI24OiAFsXEJHDBQIYNDARgGhECABopcMwkABMnADoHKxIYVj8nV3dPAF59OABtAGtgVhCi1gh0AjgAMjgyiqkauuKGnQBdanxC4ra4AB8pbtZegZ0htqVrOwcCABtZrx8-WEDg9B8XMIi4KNidBLhHGYAFJf9VuBgAC0x4TCg8ACJsDI9HuAAKZB35kU1xIIASh2DzgDwAjgBXBAPaKhGYQa5oYIfJCIxZBYAoEKYX4aMTaGjA+54XwBDy4g42JIpNIAETgOWcbg8TVI5CsVjgp185yCcA8sxK33wLCGpRalQAoiBsLNIdFgAAefDheqVZmZAB8bQA-J1xko2SxOdyzit+YLhZ5JGKyhLytLZfLFUrJGrJekWUgdfrBmUJjxjRyuTzlgFLUghSEdHbig6GjK5QrlToPY6vdq9dQxgGlEA)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share a more general answer just in case someone finds it useful.

Quite extensive, but in the end you will only need to use the `CommonUncommon` type (for lack of a better name)

```
export interface A {
  x: string;
  y: string;
}

export interface B {
  y: string;
}

export interface C {
  z: string;
  y: string;
}

export interface D {
  y: string;
  justAnotherProp: unknown[];
}

type IsInAll<T extends unknown[], Prop extends number | string | Symbol> = T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Prop extends keyof Head
    ? IsInAll<Tail, Prop>
    : false
  : true;
type ExcludeArr<T extends unknown[], X, Res extends unknown[] = []> = T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? Head extends X
    ? X extends Head
      ? ExcludeArr<Tail, X, Res>
      : ExcludeArr<Tail, X, [...Res, Head]>
    : ExcludeArr<Tail, X, [...Res, Head]>
  : Res;
type Normalize<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K]};
type Unite<T extends unknown[], K extends unknown[] = T, Res = unknown> = T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] 
  ? Unite<Tail, K, {
    [Prop in keyof Head as true extends IsInAll<ExcludeArr<K, Head>, Prop> ? Prop : never]: Head[Prop]; 
  } 
  & 
  {
    [Prop in keyof Head as false extends IsInAll<ExcludeArr<K, Head>, Prop> ? Prop : never]?: Head[Prop]; 
  }
  &
  Res>
  : Res;

type CommonUncommon<T extends unknown[]> = Normalize<Unite<T>>;

type res1 = CommonUncommon<[A, B]>;
type res2 = CommonUncommon<[A, B, C]>;
type res3 = CommonUncommon<[A, B, C, D]>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQTgG8AoOOEALjgGcYpkBzAbjLgE9q6GkWSBfEiVCRYiFGiy44AIWJtOtek1aDh4aPGSoMOPAGF55AF5dlvVuUXcVAoSM3idUvABEjHMzz7kAVgFc6fCQIGAALNAAFKAgwan8kAGsQgHckAG0AXVUhGHYwPABJGkKkfAAbcoAeABU4UFQkABMaOATkiDSsgBo4aNj6kEaWuCR-AFsAIzQ4AB8lbzm4AGV2KYhygD44AF44OobgZtb05HQZgAlgTCbegDoHs5mazARyzLYAfj6YsEHh1qJYDsCDoOBXG5scjfYqlCrVF5vXr9MCbKFwahYco0YBsaj0fzAVh5ApwACiIGw5X8TWA+CgUFq-yOI3aqQymV6AA1egAlYCtQ7HNpJdlZXZwLLbPYHIYsk5PKDg663OAPO6K-avd5fZU3ZnCrno75cg0jCFNdHQ8mU6m0+mMxHlbl8gVo8gejE2qk0ukM2ral2S9X8mi9C2Zd0e6gUn32-1OoPpEMC8MqyN4uCh4n5PAAOWg40w5QQxmAtWlxHSAGlxHAgSCwTVMtQajXMvwc6SAKpIBCoJlC1mizoc3q1oetNmj8Uy12tPbTtKV2UAyWai33R5Ic5Kp2ZOC63v98uJuDV3qkT3pFF1hugvVNOCYVoEvCTuCwsqVKqxu1+xkL0fTZkV+bZvlvagkGAAA3NAW0fG9fmyQ9yH4VC4AAMgwq8PSQgZkHrYEHwtZ9WixHEzVaL94V-W1fQdKogItECflicC2L+KDYPgz5qAtfCwBQthBHITC2FDKNqGzXJczgfQIHGcYICQXtsEU5SkEHOVhSXDlKwLKAixLMsqmPAcak2TZWBIEk8CgAUAEYJQUpSVLUjSVKqdJ8F6GQMzsuAHJoAAmFzPNUpB1LcrSfL83p9ACuTgoAZnCmKPJi7zfNkBLelcDMgA)