# Conditionally passing props in react (depending on other props)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was using such approach for passing a props conditionally (depending on another prop) in react:

```
type CommonProps = { age: number };

type ConditionalProps =
  | {
      type: 'view' | 'add';
    }
  | {
      type: 'edit';
      initialData: number;
    };

let Test = (props: CommonProps & ConditionalProps) => {
  return <div />;
};
```

My goal was:

- if `type` is passed as "view" or "add", then I want *TS to error if I pass `initialData`*
- if `type` is passed as "edit" then `initialData` should *be required*.

This actually worked most of the time, until value of `type` was dynamic.
When I passed value of `type` like this:

```
 <Test
   age={9}
   type={Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'edit' : 'view'}
   initialData={9}
 />
```

Now it seems there is bug above, because TS isn't complaining anymore, and it can happen that `type` is "view" and I *also pass* `initialData`, **which violates my first goal above**.

I am not sure maybe I am asking too much, but is there an approach which achieves my above two goals also when value of `type` is dynamic like in this example?

Comment: Please consider using `StrictUnion` helper. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) answer and my [article](https://catchts.com/unions). COmplete example [here](https://tsplay.dev/N9j1jm)

Comment: You may achieve this by the [_TypeScript Utility Types: Partial, Pick, and Omit_](https://www.skylerlemay.com/blog/2020/04/27/typescript-utility-types-part-1-partial-pick-and-omit).

Or you can read the relevant discuss [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499966/create-type-having-common-props-from-other-types-and-other-optional).

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine solution from motto below seems simpler to me, does it have some drawbacks which yours doesn't have? (what I found bit weird in motto's answer is that it gives same error even if I use `string` instead of `never`; I had tried this version myself before but ignored due to this)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava motto's solution is the same as mine. I have provided you with generic solution for all unions and motto provided you with example for your particular case. See result of `StrictUnion`, it also returns a union where disallowed property is `never`

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine when you linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties), I started looking if it was exactly similar to my example. I think they are mainly, but maybe there is a small difference because I am using discriminated unions and that example doesn't. For example see here: https://t.ly/bo4y, you see `test2` doesn't error while `test1` does. Can you explain briefly what is difference there in terms of type checking there? Or maybe I should ask new question.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava you are right, this is because `{A:1, C: 3} is assignable to {C: number}`. TS unions are tricky. This is why, I think that using discriminate unions is the safest option. If you can't use discriminator, the safest option would be to use `StrictUnion`, where all disallowed properties are `never`

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine yeah but I meant do you have idea why `test1` errors in my previous link?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava this is because it is a different case. This union type has its own discriminator `type`. Consider [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvqKMm). `test1` evaluates to `{ type: "view" | "edit"; }`whereas object has to be either `{ type: 'view' }`  or  `{ initialData: number; type: 'edit'; }`. `type` can't be in the same type either `view` or `edit` because then TS is unable to figure out whether `initialData` should be present or not. If you add `initialData` it will work. Imagine that Math.random returns `0.6`, then object should contain `initialData`, but it will not

Comment: In one of the links above, a TS demo, I had a comment stating "Here there is no error
. Probably because `{A:1, C: 3}` is assignable to `{C: number}`", which is not entirely true imho. Reason is because property `A` exists in one of the unions of type `T2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Typescript [ignores excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) unless they're explicitly assigned or passed as an argument.

So, although in your example here you're passing `{ age: number, type: "view", initialData: number }`, that satisfies the type `{ type: "view" | "add" }`. This is similar to the way that, for instance, you might ignore irrelevant fields in data from an external source.

If however you really want to ban the extra prop in this instance, you can do so by specifying that its type should be `never`:

```js
type ConditionalProps =
  | {
      type: 'view' | 'add';
      initialData?: never;
    }
  | {
      type: 'edit';
      initialData: number;
    };
```

Note that we specify `initialData` as `never` and also *optional*, so that it may (must) be omitted.

With the `never` type in place, Typescript will report an error unless the `type` prop is `"edit"`.

[Minimal repro available here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-iwm4cz)

Comment: The extra prop is being banned even without using `never`, if I don't pass `type` as `Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'edit' : 'view'` and just use "view" or "edit". So why would I use `never`?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava If you add `never` then it will forbid the extra prop

Comment: it forbids that even if I use say `string` instead of `never`: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=21&pln=8&pc=27#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCTgGFcQIA7ABRzAGc4BeOAG84KAOZIAXHFYBXEACMkUOAF8A3BSq16TVgBNgMYGxQAbThB78KcW3AA+Qm3Zc06U-ADdgSAO74HAhQ9PXwNchcXYFZDYDMAERQYFAluGCho0XCXFWdbR0E8yLdJAiQDGDCiqJijBKSU6TlFKGy7dU0IilMkeAAVJDT+OAAKMC5uKSYQFg4JuAAyRjYK41YzCx4ASn4APicIuyIYGShWOAAeA084AHpd8I7KclvbuCUcKAo0NiGAD2GFwGaSKYiQfEEAE5codbCUIQBZJIACwAdFAUPpcCMdvsAAyogCscAA-GUKgEPN4-PgYZForF6skIdCKPcgA), with similar error message

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I've linked through to a CodeSandbox, perhaps there are other differences in your code which are not reflected in your question.

Comment: did you check my above link? It gives similar message with `string` instead of `never`

Comment: My apologies @GiorgiMoniava I did not see the inline link. The "similar error message" is indeed similar – when `type` can be `"edit" | "view"` then the value of the `initialData` prop must satisfy `number & string`, which is equivalent to `never`.

Comment: But the error message doesn't say anything about `initialData`, it says "   `Type '"view"' is not assignable to type '"edit"'`. Anyway, you can see it works in such case without `never`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCTgGFcQIA7ABRzAGc4BeOAG84KAOZIAXHFYBXEACMkUOAF8A3BSq16TVgBNgMYGxQAbThB78KcW3AA+Qm3Zc06U-ADdgSAO74HAhQ9PXwNchcVZ1tHQWiXODdJAiQDGDD4l2BWQ2AzABEUGBQpWQUlcMjwmwpTJHgAFSRueAEACjAubikmEBYOLrgAMkY2NONWMwseAEp+AD4nCLsiGBkoVjgAHgNPOAB6efD1TXJ9-bglHCgKNDYWuAAPfm2mlvixJD5BAE4o5dsSW+Xh8-n+CWyuQKRRQ3z+FEOQA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251828/discussion-between-motto-and-giorgi-moniava).